# documentclass not being recognized

Tags: errors, document-classes

My tex document has the following as the first two lines:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,draft,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
```

When I run: `latex civil.tex` I get the following output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./civil.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.

 ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

 See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 
     ��\documentclass[letterpaper,draft,12pt]{article}
? 

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)
Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--284
[]|
[1]) (./civil.aux) [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14]
[15] [16] [17] [18] [19] [20] (./civil.aux) )
Output written on civil.dvi (20 pages, 72800 bytes).
Transcript written on civil.log.
```

I'm kind of new to this, I don't know what is wrong.
The document generates but the first page is blank. The rest of the document generated seems right, except that it looks like it is using a book layout (on the letterpaper the text doesn't take up that much space).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Some editors, especially on Windows, put a [BOM (*byte order mark*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of a text file. Check in the preferences of yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some non printable characters in your TeX-file before `\documentclass`. Delete the line and write it new should help, if you cannot see these two characters in your editor to delete only these two ones.

Comment: How silly of me. I saw those characters there and thought nothing of it. I ended up having to create a new file copy all of the contents of the other file except the first line (documentclass line) then manually type that line again in the new file. I tried just deleting the previous files first line and retyping and those characters were always there. This might be because that file was originally a project Gutenberg file. Strange. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As [Herbert says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23153/documentclass-not-being-recognized/23155#23155), you have garbage on the first line. Most likely, this is a [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which is sometimes inserted by various editors. Make sure to set your editor not to use this BOM when editing `.tex` files.